# Muestra mal el listado de un select

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

tengo un problema y desconozco si es una clase de bug o un error que estoy cometiendo al momento de llamar algo.
El detalle es que en un select que tengo muestro un listado de varios clientes pero al momento de dar click me sale todo el listado como debe de ser pero a su vez el listado sigue en la misma fila  de donde empieza el select.
Este es mi HTML, comparto mi select unicamente que se encuentra en un formulario.

Cliente

```
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></span>
      </div>
       <select class="form-control" id="verClienteE" >
        <option  id="verListadoCliente"></option>
       </select>  
    </div>
```

este es mi de javascript.

```
$('#verClienteE').ready(function() {

  $("#verClienteE").prop("disabled", false);
  var  clienteRFC = $("#cliente_rfc").val();  

  //alert(clienteRFC)

  var parametro = { "clienteRFC" : clienteRFC };
  $.ajax({
    data: parametro,
    url: 'modelos/pagoPedimento.modelo.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
      if(data != null)
      {
        var ClaveCliente,Nombredecliente;

        var rows = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        for (var x=0; x<rows.length; x++) {
          ClaveCliente = rows[x].ClaveCliente;
          Nombredecliente = rows[x].Nombredecliente;
          $("#verClienteE").append('<option value="'+Nombredecliente+'">'+Nombredecliente+'</option>');    
        }
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert(jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});



$('#verListadoCliente').ready(function() {

  $("#verListadoCliente").prop("disabled", false);
  var  clienteRFC = $("#cliente_rfc").val();  

  var parametro = { "clienteRFC" : clienteRFC };
  $.ajax({
    data: parametro,
    url: 'modelos/pagoPedimento.modelo.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
      if(data != null)
      {
        var ClaveCliente,Nombredecliente;

        var rows = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        for (var x=0; x<rows.length; x++) {
          ClaveCliente = rows[x].ClaveCliente;
          Nombredecliente = rows[x].Nombredecliente;
          $("#verListadoCliente").append('<option value="'+Nombredecliente+'">'+Nombredecliente+'</option>');    
        }
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert(jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

Esta parte lo que hago es mostrar los datos ya guardados en un formulario de editar.

```
$(".tablaSolicitudPago").on("click", ".btnEditarSolicitudPP", function() 
{


  var parametro = { "idEditarSolicitudPP" : idEditarSolicitudPP };

  $.ajax({
    data: parametro,
    url: 'modelos/pagoPedimento.modelo.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) 
    {
      if (data !=null) 
      {
        var 
        cliente;
      
        rows = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        
         
          cliente = rows[0].cliente;
          
          
          $("#verListadoCliente").html(cliente);
          $("#verListadoCliente").val(cliente);
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      alert(jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);
    }

  })

})
```

quiero aclarar que tengo dos select contando con este que hacen la misma función pero únicamente me sucede con este select que me ha presentado ese problema con el listado, mientras que el otro no ocurre. agradezco su tiempo en checar mi problema, estoy abierto a comentarios y sugerencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez te falta añadir un elemento `<option>` inicial que muestre un valor por defecto y no el primer valor de tu lista.

Comment: No entendí el problema

Comment: ¿Por qué el id _verListadoCliente_ está en un `option` y no en el `select` mismo?

Comment: @padaleiana el id verListadoCliente lo puse en <option> porque en el select no me mostraba el listado, entonces lo que hice fue ponerlo en el option para que funcionara y funciono. No se a que se deba sinceramente.

Comment: Si hay una mejor manera para hacer eso con todo gusto pueden modificar mi código.

Comment: Realmente hay muchas correcciones que hacer a tu código (de hecho, estás usando jQuery y no JS puro: agregalo a las etiquetas). Para empezar, revisá [var, let, const... o nada en Javascript](/q/106042). Tenés variables que se llaman igual: procurá además que se llamen de manera más descriptiva (_parametro_ no es descriptivo). Puede que por ahí también esté el problema (variables homónimas). Lo del `option` en lugar del `select` es bastante _particular_: si lográs reescribir el código de manera que quede más limpio, probablemente muchos errores se solucionarían.